# Jest hangs after running test despite done()

Tags: typescript, jestjs, knex.js

All, I'm trying to achieve is write a test case which checks for a working knex connection when some valid credentials are passed. Following test case executes fine but it doesn't complete the execution after displaying the execution summary. It gets stuck after the message "ran all tests" and I've to explicitly pass quit command. I'm calling done() but it never completes.

```
import * as Knex from "knex";
let knexClient:Knex< any, unknown>; 

beforeAll(() => {
    knexClient = Knex({
      client: "mysql",
      connection: {
        host: "127.0.0.1",
        user: "root",
        password: "some_pwd",
        database: "some_db"
      }
    });
  });
describe("Ask for knex client with running db", () => {
  it("should return a working connection", (done) => {
   return knexClient.raw("select 1+1 as result").then((res:any)=>{
       console.log(typeof(res))
       done();
   })
  })
});
```

Main question: What should I tweak so that execution completes?
Side Question: What would be async version of this test case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is usually caused by Knex keeping the connection to the underlying database process open. You can destroy the connection with an `afterAll`, and I've included the `async` version for comparison:

```
import Knex from "knex";
import { test } from "../knexfile";

describe("Database stuff", () => {
  let knexClient: Knex;

  beforeAll(() => {
    knexClient = Knex(test as Knex.Config);
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    knexClient.destroy();
  });

  it("should work without hanging at the end of the test run", async () => {
    const promise = knexClient.raw("SELECT 1+1 AS result");

    // Because .raw returns a bunch of metadata, we need to do a little more
    // to match the result
    const expected = [{ result: 2 }];
    await expect(promise).resolves.toContainEqual(expected);
  });

  it("rejects if the table doesn't exist", () => {
    const promise = knexClient("non_existant_table");

    // This also works. Note `return` is required here
    return expect(promise).rejects.toThrowError(/doesn't exist/);
  });
});
```

Couple of things. Firstly, note that I've grabbed the configuration from `knexfile.js`, and there's an assumption here that it's one directory up from your test file.

Secondly, `beforeAll` and `afterAll` only run before (and after) everything in the *file*. If you want setup before all *tests*, including those in other files, you'll need to move creating the database client out to a global setup file. See [globalSetup](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#globalsetup-string) for details.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. It solves my primary question. I'm unable to run the async version though and get a squiggly beneath async with error: "error TS2468: Cannot find global value 'Promise'.
    tests/integration/db.spec.ts:26:44 - error TS2705: An async function or method in ES5/ES3 requires the 'Promise' constructor.  Make sure you have a declaration for the 'Promise' constructor or include 'ES2015' in your `--lib` option."
Any idea?

Comment: That's going to be caused by not having `es2015` or (my preference) `esnext` in your `tsconfig.json`. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html.